# Convert military time to standard time

Tags: javascript

```
function checkTime(item) {
    if((item.value == "") || (doc.findItem('warning_checkbox').value == '1'))
        return true;
    if(fixtime(item,true,2)) {
        if(item.value/1 < "0800" || item.value > "1700") {
            item.value = "";
            alert("between 8 AM and 5 PM.");
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        item.value = "";
        alert("Invalid Time.  Time must be between 8 AM and 5 PM.");
        return true;
    }
    if(item.value < "0800" && item.value > "1700") {
        item.value = "";
        alert("between 8 AM and 5 PM.");
        return true;
    }
    fixtime(item,true,0);
}
```

I am using this function to convert standard time to military, but I can't figure out how to convert military to standard time. an example would be `1525 = 03:25 pm`.

Comment: This is a `string` value through-and-through? `var t = parseInt('1735',10) - 1200;` then split it by the colon.

Comment: you are comparing strings as integers

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare a string to an integer. You can use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert a string to a integer. If you are not retrieving a number as a string and you're instead just comparing two numbers, skip the quotes.

Your updated code should be:

```
function checkTime(item) {
    if((parseInt(item.value) == "") || (doc.findItem('warning_checkbox').value == '1'))
        return true;
    if(fixtime(item,true,2)) {
        if((parseInt(item.value) / 1) < 0800) || parseInt(item.value) > 1700) {
            item.value = "";
            alert("between 8 AM and 5 PM.");
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        item.value = "";
        alert("Invalid Time.  Time must be between 8 AM and 5 PM.");
        return true;
    }
    if(parseInt(item.value) < 0800 && parseInt(item.value) > 1700) {
        item.value = "";
        alert("between 8 AM and 5 PM.");
        return true;
    }
    fixtime(item,true,0);
}
```

Comment: unless you are planing to give a solution, this is a comment

Comment: I am writing a full solution now.

Comment: I think this is a bit redundant `item.value/1`. Also the comparison operators are switched around.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
function checkTime(item) {
    var time = parseInt(item.value);
    if(isNaN(time) || (doc.findItem('warning_checkbox').value == '1'))
        return true;
    if(fixtime(item,true,2)) {
        if(time > 800 && time < 1700) {
            item.value = "";
            alert("between 8 AM and 5 PM.");
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        item.value = "";
        alert("Invalid Time.  Time must be between 8 AM and 5 PM.");
        return true;
    }
    if(time > 800 && time < 1700) {
        item.value = "";
        alert("between 8 AM and 5 PM.");
        return true;
    }
    fixtime(item,true,0);
}
```